# Hive table Permissions

Tags: hadoop, hive, permissions, bigdata

I have a sensitive Hive table, how do I prevent authorised users making a copy (another hive table ) and share the newly created table with others ? (non -authorised users)

Comment: Probably you cant do it for any system. If authorized user wants to share with unauthorized user (illegal), no one can prevent it. In hive, you can put the table in restricted database for authorized user

Comment: Your question is very broad. Can you provide more information about the context, what you've already tried, etc? In general, I would agree with @KoushikRoy in that you can't generally prevent an authorized user from copying the data that they have access to.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.